# Call to a member function mysqli_num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql

I am new in php and sql.
I was trying to make a chat web,but i had too many errors in php, it is connected to database but im not able to Insert things in my database.
I have two errors at the time that are hard to understand for me,

## 1

```
 FATAL ERROR:Call to a member function mysqli_num_rows() on a non-object in E:\xamp\htdocs\chatting\post.php on line 20
```

## 2

```
 NOTICE:undifined index: in E:\xamp\htdocs\chatting\post.php on line 13
```

the php script that is giving these errors is

```
  <?php
  $connect= new mysqli('localhost', 'root','' ,'user');



  if($connect->connect_error){

  die('connection failed bruh');

 } else 

 echo 'connected';
 $message= $_POST[`message`];
 $name= $_POST[`name`];

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO user (name, message) VALUES (`{$name}`, `{$message}`)';

 $result = $connect-> query($sql);

 if ($result->mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
  while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo  $row[`$message`];
 }

 } else 
   echo  '<br> problem';
 ?>
```

my sql database's table name is user and it have three colmns

```
 1.id (which is set to auto increment)
 2.name
 3.message
```

if anyone can help me get rid of these  will be very thankful and if there are more errors in my php code then please tell me

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows($result)`, not the query itself.

Comment: Probably you are confusing object oriented and procedural style. Either use `$result->num_rows` or `mysqli_num_rows($result)`. What is the need for query to be passed into `mysqli_num_rows`?

Comment: Try to avoid using backticks on array keys, use either apostrophes or quotation marks (e. g. instead of ``$message= $_POST[`message`];`` do ``$message= $_POST['message'];``)

Comment: @AntonioHernández thanks very much it solved the undefined index error

Comment: @MattClark and Thamilan then what thing i have to replace with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a space here: `$result = $connect->" "query($sql);`, remove it and try again.

Make sure to avoid spacing on improper places.

Also, as I said instead of `$message= $_POST[`message`];` do `$message= $_POST['message'];`. Don't use backticks on assoc arrays key names.

Comment: THNAKS i have done it

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to echo what is being posted but your attempting to do so by creating a loop for an INSERT. You should be looping a SELECT. There are two options for you here. The easiest is to just echo what was submitted:

```
echo $message;
```

If what you're trying to do is verify that the query was true, then you can do something like:

```
if ( $result = $connect-> query($sql) )
{
    echo $message;
} else
{
    echo  '<br> problem';
}
```

Comment: THANKS IT HAS SOLVED 70% problem of my script

Comment: No prob. On a side note, look into sanitizing the inputs or using PDO once you get things figured out. It'll help patch some vulnerabilities in your script.

Comment: ok, I have done that but the message is not displaying but its saving in database

Comment: its displaying PROBLEM i dont know why,.my code has become           **<?php
$connect= new mysqli('localhost', 'root','' ,'user');



if($connect->connect_error){

    die('connection failed bruh');

} else 

echo 'connected';
$message= $_POST['message'];
$name= $_POST['name'];

$sql = 'SELECT FROM user (name, message) VALUES (`{$name}`, `{$message}`)';

$result = $connect-> query($sql);

if ($result= $connect-> query($sql))
{
 echo "its done";
    echo "the message is:$message";
} else
{
    echo  '<br> problem';
}
?>**

Comment: Your select statement is wrong. You just replaced the word INSERT with SELECT which isn't how it works. Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html to learn about select queries. Also, $result = $connect-> query($sql); is stated twice. You only need it in the if($result = $connect-> query($sql) ) for it to fire off the query. If you have questions about your query and its formatting you should probably start another question.

Comment: i will do that, and thanks